# Error: need a repository as argument

Tags: installation, kubuntu, ppa, repository

i am kind of new in Linux, and i am using kubuntu and i keep getting this error when installing a package in terminal, i tried java, openshot, any ppa package and i keep getting "Error: nedd a repository as argument". I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Example:

```
kristyano1987@kristyano1987-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/javasudo apt-get updatesudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
Error: need a repository as argument"
```

Answer (score 4):

No wonder, you're running the commands in a wrong way. It must be executed in multiple lines or at least with `&&` separating the commands.

The correct sequence of commands would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```