# Installing libraries for python

Tags: python3

Guy's a have a little problem here because I can't figure out how to install my python libraries like media pipe and open-cv. Is it possible to run my codes from windows to ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: need a repository as argument](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115624/error-need-a-repository-as-argument)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install mediapipe
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

Comment: How about "Error: need repository as an argument"? thank you